# iOS: subviews not added to the parent UIView?

Tags: ios, ipad

I have a parent UIView with several subviews but these are not visible and they don't reconize gestures, so I'm afraid they have not been added.. or something went wrong.

The subviews class is ImageWithCaptionView, a subclass of UIView. I've created a ImageWithCaptionView.xib file and wired 2 IBOutlets: UIImageView and UILabel.

I'm sure the xib file is linked with the ImageWithCaptionView class because I've wired the IBOutlets.

What am I doing wrong here ? Why can't I see the subviews ? This is the code:

```
    ImageWithCaptionView* imageWithCaptionView = [[ImageWithCaptionView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(offset, 0.0, 320.0, 330.0)];


    UIGestureRecognizer *recognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleTap:)];

    [(UITapGestureRecognizer *)recognizer setNumberOfTouchesRequired:1];

    imageWithCaptionView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    [imageWithCaptionView addGestureRecognizer:recognizer];
    recognizer.delegate = self;
    [recognizer release];

    dispatch_queue_t downloadQueue = dispatch_queue_create("Flickr downloader in EventsTableView", NULL);

    dispatch_async(downloadQueue, ^{

        NSData *image = [FlickrFetcher imageDataFromPhotoId:object]; 

        if(image) {

            //I'm sure this code, inside if statement runs
            imageWithCaptionView.imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData: image]; 

        }
    });

    imageWithCaptionView.label.text = @"test label"; 


    dispatch_release(downloadQueue);

    [cell addSubview:imageWithCaptionView];
    [imageWithCaptionView release];
```

thanks

Update, Log:

```
   2011-05-08 14:34:40.915 FlickrBrowser[26524:207] (null)
   2011-05-08 14:34:40.917 FlickrBrowser[26524:207] {{nan, 2.34559e-38}, {-1.9979, 2.22702e-38}}
   2011-05-08 14:34:40.920 FlickrBrowser[26524:207] (null)
   2011-05-08 14:34:40.923 FlickrBrowser[26524:207] {{5.31614e-36, 5.31614e-36}, {6.74717e-39, 6.74717e
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you don't set your subviews' frame anywhere, so they all have zero frame by default and that's why they appear invisible on your parent view.

Comment: @Vladimir thanks, that was the issue indeed. Now the gestures work, but I still can't see the picture or the label. The code inside the if statement runs correctly.. I've also tried to assign the text to the label in the main thread but i can't see it

Comment: You can check if [UIImage imageWithData: image] returns valid image + check if imageWithCaptionView's subviews themselves have non-zero frames...

Comment: @Vladimir I'm 100% sure that the view is there, because it recognizes gestures. However its elements are invisible.

Comment: Well i'm syntetizing them and I've wired them from UIBuilder. They should have frames right ? What's the best way to check it ?

Comment: If you create your view using alloc/init method then it won't get loaded from nib file - so most likely your subviews are nil. Check if your subviews are created and check their frames, e.g. by nslogging their values: NSLog(@"%@",imageWithCaptionView.imageView) and NSLog(@"%@",NSStringFromCGRect(imageWithCaptionView.imageView.frame))

Comment: @Vladimir Ok, so the subViews are null, but the frame not (See log in the updated question). So I guess I'm correctly defining the frame, but the views are not initialized ? I've wired them from UIBuilder and used #property/@synthesize in ImageWithCaptionView, I thought they are initialized in this way.

Comment: As you can see from the code I'm not using alloc/init method, for instance, I'm just assigning the string to the Label: imageWithCaptionView.label.text = @"test label";

Comment: @Patrick, yes but as you create your ImageWithCaptionView instance with alloc/init it won't be loaded from nib file and so its subviews won't get created. And as subviews are nil (not created) then frame values are invalid and so logs output does not make real sense

Comment: To load view from nib you need to use loadNibNamed method in NSBundle or UINib class (I have no experience with the latter, but if I remember correctly it is much better option as it performs better on multiple loads)

Comment: @Vladimir All right, now it is clear why it didn't work! Anyway, isn't counterintuitive the fact that I'm wiring MyView and the objects in xib file and I'm writing myViewSubClass in the xib Inspector Identifier, and then if I initialize such subclass, the xib file is totally ignored ? Anyway I will check for UINib based instantation now.